# Nodejs app deployed in CentOS 7 with Apache not accessible by domain

Tags: node.js, apache, centos, centos7

I'm trying to deploy my app in CentOS 7 with Apache but even though the app is running, it is not accessible neither by the domain.

When I try to visit with the domain, it says `Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource`.

Please note that I can access the website with ip:port.

This is the configuration for Apache in `sites-available` directory with file name `example.com.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName  example.com
        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPass / http://server-ip:3000
        ProxyPassReverse / http://server-ip:3000
</VirtualHost>
```

I also added `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf` inside `httpd.conf` file.

I'm not used to CentOS 7 and neither with Apache so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Also note that the domain is configured with CloudFlare and I think the domain has SSL installed as I can see in the browser, it doesn't say 'Not Secure'. It is also worth mentioning that the server host is Private Cloud Server with DirectAdmin.

==============UPDATE===============

This is what I tried after Alaindeseine suggested:

```
<VirtualHost example.com:80>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
        RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"

        ServerName example.com

        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$"no-gzip
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript

        ExpiresActive On
        ProxyRequests off
        RequestHeader add original-protocol-ssl 1
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        <Location />
                ProxyPass http://ip:3000/
                ProxyPassReverse http://ip:3000/
                ProxyPreserveHost On
        </Location>
        # SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.example.com/cert.pem
        # SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.example.com/privkey.pem
        # Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        # SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If think you need to change from ip-address to localhost

Here is a full example of apache virtualhost with SSL:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.example.com:80>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
        RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000"

        ServerName xxx.example.com

        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$"no-gzip
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript

        ExpiresActive On
        ProxyRequests off
        RequestHeader add original-protocol-ssl 1
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        <Location />
                ProxyPass http://localhost:3511/
                ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3511/
                ProxyPreserveHost On
        </Location>
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx.example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

You can naturally remove all ssl configuration.

Also, don't leave ProxyRequest to On because open proxy may be dangerous if not secured: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyrequests

Comment: Hey, are SERVER_PORT, SERVER_NAME and REQUEST_URI placeholders here for values or should I leave them as it is and actually just replace example.com to my domain?

Comment: @Zak SERVER_PORT, SERVER_NAME and REQUEST_URI are apache vars. So you just have to replace xxx.example.com and th 3511 port by yours.

Comment: Hey, I used the config above and then after I restart httpd and check apache status, I see this: ```[core:error] [pid 17169] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00549: Failed to resolve server name for 104.xx.xx.204 (check DNS) -- or specify an explicit ServerName```. If I use a dns lookup of the domain, then it resolves to two CloudFlare IPs. and one of them is the above one in the error.

Comment: Can you provide your virtualhost conf?

Comment: I'm using your one now. Changed only the things you told me to.

Comment: @Zak I have understand this, but what i want to see is what you have replaced!

Comment: Updated the OP. Please check

Comment: @Zak about these lines: ``ProxyPass http://ip:3000/
                ProxyPassReverse http://ip:3000/``. Does ip correspond to the ip that finished wit`.204`in te error message?
If yes, and if your node.js server is on the same serveur, replace ip by `localhost`.
In you example you indicate `xxx.example.com`for the ServerName directive. Have you replace this with the IP address which end with`.204`? Or by a real server nmae?

Comment: If your server name is a local one (like myserver.local), have you added an entry in your local /etc/hosts file?

Comment: About your first question, ip with .204 is Cloudflare ip which gets resolved when I do a dns lookup. There's also another CF ip which I get beside .204 as well. So no, the ip I'm using with 3000 is not .204 ip but rather my server IP. About your second question, yes I have added that (127.0.0.1  domain) in etc/hosts but I dont think that's necessary as I'm using CF, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Also, in proxypass, I added the server ip because my app is accessible with serverIp:3000

Comment: Just test with serverIp:80 instead of example.com:80 in <VirtualHost example.com:80>. I'm not seeing that error anymore but website is sitll not accessible by domain